# Enter each subfolder of a main folder and read a certain file type from each?

Tags: python, loops, operating-system

A folder `A` has subfolders `B,C,D` that contains new 'under consideration' files.There's also another similar folder with similar subfolders that has valid corresponding files.

All these subfolders contain the same file types.i have to make a program that opens these folders and reads first a certain `.shp` file that is there ( only one `.shp` exists in each subfolder,`B,C,D`) and does some procedures which i have already solved. The problem is only how to do the initial thing that i described.

i tried the glob library:

```
from glob import glob
glob("directory/*/")
```

which now provides the subdirectories of the main folder. But i don't know if that is helpful for the process.

To read these `shp` files i use

```
import fiona
d1 = fiona.open('hxc.shp)
```

so the code is :

```
import os
import fiona
new=input('Select directory of new folder:      ')
old=input('Select directory of old folder:   ')


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(DIRECTORY\Desktop\a'):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".shp")):
          d1= fiona.open(os.path.join(root, name))
```

That last part doesn't read all the subfolders in that main folder that each contains an shp. It just assigns one `.shp` file. I want to read each subfolder that has an `shp` extension and assign it to a new variable.

The working code to pass in a list each shp from every directory is this:

**UPDATE**$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

```
rootdir = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\a' # path to your root directory you walk
sfiles = [] # a list with all the .shp files
for entry in os.listdir(rootdir):
    dirpath = os.path.join(rootdir, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(dirpath): 
        for file in os.listdir(dirpath): # Get all files in the subdirectories
            if file.endswith('.shp'): # If it's an .shp.
                filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
                sfiles.append(fiona.open(filepath))
```

---

**The main task is the following:**

One main folder A with B,C,D... subfolders. This main folder has **new** under consideration files.**Most** of the subfolders have shps.

There is one other main folder though. Let's call it K with L,M,N.. subfolders.These subfolders are the corresponding from the other subfolders of the other folder with the **new** files.

I want the user to insert the directory of the main `A` folder and read the first shp from the first subfolder (if it exists an shp there) then go to the other `old` main folder and check the corresponding subfolder, get the `shp` from there *and do some comparisons between them and print the results*(the italics parts i have already solved them)and then continue with the rest of the `new` folder's subfolders accordingly.If in one subfolder there is not an shp it should print:'folder name' has no shp. and continue with the rest.

How should i do it?

---

When should i add this combination between each shapefiles.schema piece?
if the shapefiles were inserted manually i would do it like this:

```
pst_n=fiona.open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\new\PST')#new pst
pst_o=fiona.open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\old\PST')#old_pst
pst_n.schema
d1 = pst_n.schema['properties']
d2 = pst_o.schema['properties']

d1_items = set(d1.items())
d2_items = set(d2.items())
result = sorted([(k, 'd1', v) for k, v in d1_items if (k, v) not in d2_items] +
                [(k, 'd2', v) for k, v in d2_items if (k, v) not in d1_items])

result = [(k, v, d) for k, d, v in result]


pprint(result)
```

and shows the differences like that:

```
[('ADDRESS', 'int:4', 'd1'),
 ('ADDRESS', 'str:254', 'd2'),
 ('AREA', 'float:19.11', 'd2'),
 ('DEC_ID', 'int:4', 'd1'),
 ('DEC_ID', 'str:254', 'd2'),
 ('DESC_', 'str:254', 'd1'),
 ('FID_PERIVL', 'int:9', 'd1'),
 ('KAEK', 'str:50', 'd1'),
 ('KAEK', 'str:12', 'd2'),
 ('LEN', 'float:19.11', 'd2'),
```

Now how should i show each combination's differences as it loops?

Comment: Have you considered appending to a list instead of assigning to a variable ?

Comment: I want to use each variable for further process so variable would be better in my opinion.

Comment: You could also use each element of the list for further process, or maybe using a dictionary with file paths as keys would be better ? (see answer from @blhsing)

Comment: How do i access each subfolder of the main folder automatically?i don't search for a specific file just every .shp file in each subfolder IF it exists.

Comment: check the updated version of my question and think accordingly.Here is the data to check if it works what you will try to do:http://www.mediafire.com/file/644y8e12pj9jrei/main_folders.zip

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning the file streams to a fixed variable `d1`, you should assign them to a dict indexed by path names.

```
file = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('DIRECTORY\Desktop\a'):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(".shp"):
            path = os.path.join(root, name)
            file[path] = fiona.open(path)
```

Comment: How do i access each subfolder of the main folder automatically?i don't search for a specific file just every .shp file in each subfolder IF it exists.

Comment: That's what `os.walk` does. It recursively traverses all subfolders and their subfolders to return a full list of files under the given directory, so no matter where your `.shp` files hide, it will find them all.

Comment: It says: `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: Did you assign a string to `file` somehow? `file` needs to be initialized as a dict with `{}`. I just edited my answer with initialization for `file`.

Comment: check the updated version of my question and think accordingly.Here is the data to check if it works what you will try to do: http://www.mediafire.com/file/644y8e12pj9jrei/main_folders.zip

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you rather go with `os.listdir()` than `os.walk()`:

```
rootdir1 = '/path/to/dir' # path to your root directory you walk
rootdir2 = '/path/to/other/dir' # path to your 2nd main directory
sfiles1 = [] # a list with all the .shp files in the old subdirectories
sfiles2 = [] # a list with the .shp files in the new subdirectories
fpaths = [] # a list to check all gathered file paths not to duplicate
sdirs1 = [] # a list with all old subdirectories that contain an '.shp' 
sdirs2 = [] # a list with all new subdirectories with that .shp file
for entry in os.listdir(rootdir1):
    dirpath = os.path.join(rootdir1, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(dirpath): 
        for file in os.listdir(dirpath):
            if file.endswith('.shp'):
                if dirpath not in sdirs1:
                    sdirs1.append(dirpath) # add old subdirectories to list
for entry in os.listdir(rootdir2):
    dirpath = os.path.join(rootdir2, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(dirpath):
        for file in os.listdir(dirpath):
            if file.endswith('.shp'):
                if dirpath not in sdirs2:
                    sdirs2.append(dirpath) # add new subdirectories to list
# Then open files from old and new dir
for d in sdirs1:
    for f in os.listdir(d):
        if f.endswith('.shp') and f not in fpaths: # check not to duplicate
            fp = os.path.join(d, f)
            fpaths.append(fp)
            sfiles1.append(fiona.open(fp))
for d in sdirs2:
    for f in os.listdir(d):
        if f.endswith('.shp') and f not in fpaths:
            fp = os.path.join(d, f)
            fpaths.append(fp)
            sfiles2.append(fiona.open(fp))
```

Then I believe `sfiles1[0]` from the old main directory should correspond to `sfiles2[0]` from the new main directory. You are free to make the needed changes for your code to work, this is just a guideline. 
Note: the folder input **must** be absolute (e.g. /home/asd/dir and not just dir)

If the subdirectories (old and new) will have the same names:

```
rootdir1 = '/path/to/dir' # path to your root directory you walk
rootdir2 = '/path/to/other/dir' # path to your 2nd main directory
sfiles1 = [] # a list with all the .shp files in the old subdirectories
sfiles2 = [] # a list with the .shp files in the new subdirectories
fpaths = [] # a list to check all gathered file paths not to duplicate
sdirs1 = [] # a list with all old subdirectories that contain an '.shp' 
sdirs2 = [] # a list with all new subdirectories with that .shp file
for entry in os.listdir(rootdir1):
    dirpath = os.path.join(rootdir1, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(dirpath): 
        for file in os.listdir(dirpath):
            if file.endswith('.shp'):
                if dirpath not in sdirs1:
                    sdirs1.append(dirpath) # add old subdirectories
                    sdirs2.append(os.path.join(rootdir2, entry)) # add new subdirectories to list (since the names are the same

# Then open files from old and new dir
for d in sdirs1:
    for f in os.listdir(d):
        if f.endswith('.shp') and f not in fpaths: # check not to duplicate
            fp = os.path.join(d, f)
            fpaths.append(fp)
            sfiles1.append(fiona.open(fp))
for d in sdirs2:
    for f in os.listdir(d):
        if f.endswith('.shp') and f not in fpaths:
            fp = os.path.join(d, f)
            fpaths.append(fp)
            sfiles2.append(fiona.open(fp))
```

This way **sdirs1** and **sdirs2** will always correspond, as they have the same names, just different root paths.

Comment: @user9988562 I'll edit my answer, I thought you want to save the directories. We'll simply change the name to the list from sdirs to sfiles and then after `if file.endswith('.shp'):` we'll append it's path to the sfiles list.

Comment: I fixed it. I didn't know you need that, misunderstood you. Just have to append the **fil** object to the **sfiles** list, where **fil** is the file you have opened via `fiona.open()` (e.g. `fil = fiona.open(filepath)`)

Comment: Great.One last remark and i will choose your answer.Can you answer the first part of the question too?How to check the first main folder and its subfolders like you did but after one subfolder that finds that actually has a shp file to check the other main subfolder with the valid shp then the next combination?How do i do that?

Comment: I don't really get your question. You want to also save the subfolders that have a '.shp' file to a variable, or you want to get the first subfolder with an '.shp' file and then check all other subfolders if they have the **exact same** '.shp' file? I'll edit my answer after I understand a little better what you want me to add.

Comment: @user9988562 I think I kind of got what you wanted and edited my answer accordingly. Now you have both the subdirectories and the files saved, and you can iterate in two seperate ways as I've shown. If I've gotten it wrong, correct me and I'll edit my answer again.

Comment: Understood, I'll edit my answer, but one question. Are the old and new subdirectories names the same? Like is the name of B == name of L?

Comment: I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Fixed it. Had to add the full path to the file

Comment: For **pst_n** and **pst_o** use **sfiles2** and **sfiles1**:
`counter = 0`
`for f in sfiles2:`
`pst_n = f`
`psn_o = sfiles1[counter]`
`counter += 1`
And in that for cycle put your code.

Comment: here are the data. The two main folders with their subfolders. If you want to check it how it works with the additional code. I cant make it work. http://www.mediafire.com/file/644y8e12pj9jrei/main_folders.zip

Comment: Also how exactly does it check in pairs?If you can combine all the code in order to work would be great.Check the files to test it.